# Swift iOS dim whole table view except one cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to highlight a single table cell (possibly more than one) by presenting a dim overlay on everything else except this cell. So far I am able to do that with looping through all visible cells in table and updating each cell's content view background color. On top of that I need to update navigation bar and some other container. Then I need to also unhighlight that cell once operation is done, which means a whole reversed process of manually setting backgrounds of cells and nav bar. Is there a more elegant/simple way to do it?

What I'm trying to achieve: note that inside cell I have my custom container, that I need to in case of highlight - keep highlighted, in all other cases dim together with the rest of the screen:
[image]

Comment: it's will be a broad discussion without visible context. could you please post the UI and what you have done so far to achieve this?

Comment: What about adding a UIView above your UITableView, with a mask which would be the cell frame? Or, do you want to still being able to scroll too?

Comment: hmm, tough one. Scrolling is part of the deal yeah, but I could say for the time of highlight scrolling not allowed (it's a short temporary state)

Comment: Another approach would be to have an indicator in your data model and use a diffable data source for the tableview along with appropriate logic in the cell provider closure.  This would allow you to just apply a snapshot to the datasource to turn highlighting on/off which would handle updating the cells for you.  Due to optimisation of this API I suspect this would be far more efficient in updating the UI and it would handle scrolling.  It also keep you UI code far simpler and lets you work with the model to change appearance.

Comment: you are right, my approach only updates visible cells, so in the end it's not reliable. I already have the data model nicely separated, and cells view models are diffable as well already, so it's a one more step to add this to data model and make it proper.. was hoping for quick solution for overlay, but it seems the best way to go.